# Send file input to php with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send a file from an input to a php script, using ajax.
Here is what I've done so far:

HTML

```
  <div id="inserting">
     <button id="inserting_btn">Upload</button>
     <input type="file" id="inserting_file"/>
   </div>
```

JS

```
$('#inserting_btn').click(function(){
        var file = $('#inserting_file').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'input_text/import.php',
            data: 'file='+file,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP file import.php

```
if ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ){
       echo 'yes';
    }
    else {
        echo 'no';
    }
```

(Sorry for my english.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Comment: I just use -  data: { "file": file },

Answer (score 1):

```
data: {file: file}
```

try replacing your data line with this

and in php

```
 $file = $_POST['file'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this in your code :

```
$('#inserting_btn').click(function(){
    var file_rec = $('#inserting_file').prop("files")[0]; // get the file
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_rec);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'input_text/import.php',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP file import.php

```
if ($_FILES['file']){
   echo 'yes';
}
else {
    echo 'no';
}
```